# Correctly setting resolv.conf domain

Tags: linux, dns, fedora

I'm having problems with resolving domains at work. The domain is company.local . When I connect, my `etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain company.local
search company.local
nameserver 10.0.0.60
nameserver 10.0.0.61
```

I can fix the problem (hosts not getting resolved) by doing editing the file to:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain company.local.
search company.local. office.company.local.
nameserver 10.0.0.60
nameserver 10.0.0.61
```

How can I set these more permanently? Something in `/etc/sysconfig/network`? I'm on fedora 17.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` is being populated based on the response got from the DHCP server.

Best solution for you would be to start using `dnsmasq` as the `DNS resolver` instead of the default DNS resolver.

This way you can specify additional search domains through config files which would not be over-written. Let me know and I can guide you through the steps for setting up `dnsmasq` as your DNS resolver.

If you already have dnsmasq configured, these are the lines you would need to add to your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` based on the info you posted.

```
server=/office.company.local/10.0.0.60
server=/office.company.local/10.0.0.61
```

Comment: I already seem to have `dnsmasq` installed. The manpage is insanely big. What should I do exactly?